# bind9 for DNS64 and dnsmasq for RAs and local DNS

Tags: linux, dns, dnsmasq

I need to run bind9 as a DNS64 server on four interfaces and dnsmasq for DNS resolution for the loopback interface and to provide Router Advertisements for the DNS64 interfaces.

bind9 is active on interfaces: gphy0, gphy1, gphy2 and gphy3 (addresses are, respectively: fd70:1234:1234::/64, fd70:1234:1234:1::/64, fd70:1234:1234:2::/64 and fd70:1234:1234:3::/64).
I have configured bind9 to only listen on those interfaces:

```
listen-on-v6 { fd70:3d33:7f39::/64; fd70:3d33:7f39:1::/64; fd70:3d33:7f39:2::/64; fd70:3d33:7f39:3::/64;};
```

This is working as expected and I get DNS64 resolutions:

```
root@host:~# netstat -tulpn | grep 53
tcp6       0      0 fd70:3d33:7f39:3:d09:53 :::*                    LISTEN      1232/named
tcp6       0      0 fd70:3d33:7f39:2:a81:53 :::*                    LISTEN      1232/named
tcp6       0      0 fd70:3d33:7f39:1:fcf:53 :::*                    LISTEN      1232/named
tcp6       0      0 fd70:3d33:7f39:0:903:53 :::*                    LISTEN      1232/named
tcp6       0      0 fd70:3d33:7f39:3:::53   :::*                    LISTEN      1232/named
tcp6       0      0 fd70:3d33:7f39:2:::53   :::*                    LISTEN      1232/named
tcp6       0      0 fd70:3d33:7f39:1:::53   :::*                    LISTEN      1232/named
tcp6       0      0 fd70:3d33:7f39:::53     :::*                    LISTEN      1232/named
udp6       0      0 fd70:3d33:7f39:3:d09:53 :::*                                1232/named
udp6       0      0 fd70:3d33:7f39:2:a81:53 :::*                                1232/named
udp6       0      0 fd70:3d33:7f39:1:fcf:53 :::*                                1232/named
udp6       0      0 fd70:3d33:7f39:0:903:53 :::*                                1232/named
udp6       0      0 fd70:3d33:7f39:3:::53   :::*                                1232/named
udp6       0      0 fd70:3d33:7f39:2:::53   :::*                                1232/named
udp6       0      0 fd70:3d33:7f39:1:::53   :::*                                1232/named
udp6       0      0 fd70:3d33:7f39:::53     :::*                                1232/named
```

Now I would like dnsmasq to provide DNS resolution on the loopback interface only and also enable Router Advertisements on those gphyX interfaces.
Here is my dnsmasq.conf:

```
domain-needed
bogus-priv
resolv-file=/run/resolv.conf
server=/domain.com/8.8.8.8
user=daemon
group=daemon
no-hosts
interface=
bind-interfaces
dhcp-range=::,constructor:gphy0,ra-only,12h
dhcp-range=::,constructor:gphy1,ra-only,12h
dhcp-range=::,constructor:gphy2,ra-only,12h
dhcp-range=::,constructor:gphy3,ra-only,12h
enable-ra
```

With *bind-interfaces* and *interface=* I am attempting to only run dnsmasq on the loopback interfaces (to proivide local DNS resolution). Unfortunately, this seems to break RAs (I see no RAs in a gphy0 tcpdump).

If I replace those two configuration keys with *port=0*, I get RAs on gphyX interfaces (and working DNS64), but, obviously, no local DNS resolution.

How can I have both bind9 (for DNS64 only on those four interfaces) and dnsmasq (for local DNS resolution and RA for thos four interfaces) simultaneously active?

Please let me know if any relevant information is missing and I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace with `port=20054` to run dnsmasq's DNS service on a non-standard port, then define a `forward` or `static-stub` zone in BIND to pass-through queries for your "internal" domain to Dnsmasq, while letting BIND handle all other DNS resolution. (Similar to what one would do with HTTP-based services behind a reverse-proxy.)